# An inequality in expected values of Random Variable with different PDFs

Tags: probability, solution-verification, expected-value, jensen-inequality

> **Problem.** Prove that
> $$E[\log f(X)] \ge E [\log q(X)], $$
> if $X$ is a random variable with PDF $f(x)$ and $q(x)$ is any valid PDF.
>
> *Hint provided:* Use Jensen's Inequality.

This means:

\begin{gather*}
E [\log f(X)]
= \int f(x) \log f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\ge E[\log q(X)]
= \int f(x) \log q(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\[0.75em]
\implies
-\int f(x) \log \biggl(\frac{q(x)}{f(x)}\biggr) \, \mathrm{d}x \ge 0.
\end{gather*}

Now, I am unable to understand how to move forward to use Jensen's inequality and thus get according expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ E\biggl[ \frac{g(X)}{f(X)} \biggr]
= \int \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= 1 .$$

By Jensen's inequality applied to the convex function $-\log x$ we get

$$ 0
= -\log E\biggl[ \frac{g(X)}{f(X)} \biggr]
\le - E \biggl[ \log \frac{g(X)}{f(X)} \biggr]
= - E [\log g(X)] + E [\log f(X)]. $$

Hence, $E[\log g(X)] \leq E[\log f(X)]$.

Comment: Perfect
Thank you!!